# Frogger, river Problems

Tags: java

To beat my game i have it that whenever you land on a lilypad it adds the lilypad (0-4)as a number to a string. Then to see if you win the string must contain all numbers 0-4. How can i make this possible? I initially had this but this doesn't work because im checking at all the spots at i.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < win.length(); i++) {
if (win.charAt(i) == '0' && win.charAt(i) =='1' && win.charAt(i) =='2' && win.charAt(i)=='3' && win.charAt(i)=='4'){
        System.out.print("YOU WON COMPLETELY");
      }
```

The string is win and it does not need to contain all the numbers in order, it just needs to contain them.

Comment: You could use a set of integer: `Set<Integer>` to "hold" your numbers. And then check if the size is 5: `if (set.size() == 5) { win ... }`. A set avoids duplicates, that means this set needs 5 *different* numbers (like from 0 to 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate is impossible to satisfy.  Think about it.  On the first iteration i = 0, and you're saying:

```
if(win.charAt(0) == '0' && win.charAt(0) == '1' ...
```

already, this is a logical impossibility.  You could try the approach Tom suggested and keep a `Set<Integer>` to track unique integers that represent occupied lilipods.

As a side note, if you ran your program through a debugger, what I said would be obvious.  Use an IDE, step through your code.  Otherwise, you are in the dark.